# Not able to find data from my mongodb collection using $nearSphere

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following rows in my place collection.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("572b3892967c76c62b7f63e3"), "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -73.97, 40.77 ] }, "name" : "Central Park", "category" : "Parks" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("572b38ba967c76c62b7f63e4"), "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -73.88, 40.78 ] }, "name" : "La Guardia Airport", "category" : "Airport" }
```

I am not able to execute following query

```
db.places.find({$nearSphere: {$geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-73.92, 40.775]}, $minDistance: 10000, $maxDistance: 10}})
```

I get following error:
`Error: error: { "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $nearSphere", "code" : 17287 }`

Please let me know what is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query object, the "loc" field is missing. Moreover, I think you declared the minDistance and maxDistance wrong, since maxDistanace < minDistance.

I think the query you want is something like:

```
db.places.find({loc:{$nearSphere: {$geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-73.92, 40.775]}, $minDistance: 10, $maxDistance: 10000}}})
```